exim error: NUL character(s) present (shown as '?')
I'm getting the NUL character(s) present error on exim, similar to this post, but since that post is too old, I'm following Charles Davis suggestion to create a new question.
$ tail -f /var/log/exim4/mainlog

2024-07-12 22:43:38 SMTP syntax error in "\026\003\001\002?\001?\001\374\003\003"\365\bZ\327b\277\373\261\032\246\217\275R\314b\201b\351\253k\304\001\3343/256/243/005/215U/301/207/311/227N/306e2+/216/226/307/361?0/023/002/023/003/023/001/300+/300/?/236/314/251/314/250/300" H=localhost [::1] NUL character(s) present (shown as '?')'>\\213fn\263N\303\244 \256'z\226o\305eE\231.:\234>3\256\243\005\215U\301\207\311\227N\306e2+\216\226\307\361?0\023\002\023\003\023\001\300+\300/?\236\314\251\314\250\300" H=localhost [::1] NUL character(s) present (shown as '?')
2024-07-12 22:43:38 SMTP syntax error in "\300\024?9\300        \300\023?3?\234?5?/\3000\300,?=?j?8?2?\377\001?\001\203???\016?\f??     localhost?\v?\004\003?\001\002?" H=localhost [::1] NUL character(s) present (shown as '?')
2024-07-12 22:43:38 SMTP syntax error in "?\f?" H=localhost [::1] NUL character(s) present (shown as '?')
2024-07-12 22:43:38 SMTP syntax error in "?\035?\027?\036?\031?\030?#???\005?\005\001?????\026???\027???\r?*?(\004\003\005\003\006\003\b\007\b\b\b      \b" H=localhost [::1] NUL character(s) present (shown as '?')
2024-07-12 22:43:38 SMTP call from localhost [::1] dropped: too many syntax or protocol errors (last command was "?\035?\027?\036?\031?\030?#???\005?\005\001?????\026???\027???\r?*?(\004\003\005\003\006\003\b\007\b\b\b      \b", NULL)

Exim: 4.94.2-7+deb11u3.  version 4.94.2 #2 built 09-Jul-2024 09:01:33
Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Kernel: 5.15.83-1-pve

On terminal this works fine
echo 'hi!' | mail -s "Sent from $(hostname) at $(date +"%F %T")" mail@example.com

The problem arise when sending emails from a web app installed on the host (Koha).
How could I debug the issue to find out if the web app is sending invalid strings?

The problem was on the web app setup. It was trying to connect to exim using SSL.
Context: I was confident it wasn't an encoding issue, and couldn't convert those chars to anything but gibberish, so in a moment of what if.. I disabled SSL and that did the trick.
Those first bytes are the TLS 'client hello' message, the first of the handshake. Another example here.

\026 (0x16 in hexadecimal) indicates a handshake message, the start of a TLS client hello.
\003\001 (0x0301 in hexadecimal) indicates the older v1.0. The current standard is TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.


The question asks, “How could I debug the issue to find out if the web app is sending invalid strings?”    So, how did you debug it?

In my opinion, you should take the explanation that you just wrote in the above comment and put it in the answer.    Possibly without the “Homer” reference.

Not that it helps now, but the byte sequence in octal 026 003 001* small any 001 000 small any is a perfect match for the beginning of a TLS-was-SSL ClientHello message, and practically nothing else (* the byte at offset 2, which is version.low, may be 002 or 003 but is usually 001 or rarely 000)

@dave_thompson_085 Thanks! I added more info based on this. As you said, the strange bit is the next \002\000\001\000 (\000→? by exim).

First, 026 indicates any handshake record, not just clienthello. The next two bytes are the version in some records, but not always for clienthello, and in TLS1.3 they are clamped at either 003 001 or 003 003 and the actual version is elsewhere. The next two bytes are the record length which for your example is 002 000 but in other cases could be any small byte then any byte, hence my 'small any'. The next 001 is the message type = clienthello; the next three are the message length which in your example is 000 001 374 but as I said could be 000 small any.
